# Работает плавное открытие popup, но быстро закрывает

Tags: javascript, css, popup, transition

думаю проще будет посмотреть функционал на сайте [здесь](https://eugenescheglov.github.io/mesto/). Открывает медленно , но закрывает почему-то быстро.

```css
.popup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.popup_opened {
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется visibility не анимируемое.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у вас на сайте transition: visibility 0s. Поставьте 0,5s.
Во-вторых, перенесите все статичные свойства в основной класс.

```
.popup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

А в модицифицирующем оставьте только изменяемые

```
.popup_opened {   
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!